# ADODB Recordset Does Not Add New Records In Temporary Table in MS SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, vba, adodb

I want to create a temporary table with two fields "ID" and "TempData". Then wants to insert data into that table from an excel sheet through looping. I created temporary table but when I try to add data into that table then it fails. Does anyone have idea to move an excel column values to a temporary table without looping?
Can anyone please help.

```
Sub MPNTEST()

Dim dbCon As ADODB.Connection, dbt As ADODB.Recordset, dbtf As ADODB.Field, r As Range, SqlQry1 As String
Set dbCon = New ADODB.Connection
Set dbt = New ADODB.Recordset
dbCon.ConnectionString = SqlConStr
On Error GoTo CloseConnection

SqlQry1 = "Use tempdb CREATE TABLE #TempTbl ( ID INT Primary KEY IDENTITY(1,1),TempData NVARCHAR(255))"

dbCon.Open   
dbCon.Execute (SqlQry1)

With dbt
    .ActiveConnection = dbCon
    .Source = "#TempTbl"
    .LockType = adLockOptimistic
    .CursorType = adOpenForwardOnly
    .Open
    For Each r In ActiveSheet.Range("AE2:AE10")
        .AddNew
        .Fields("TempData").Value = r.Value
        .Update                                               '###Here it fails
    Next r
End With
dbt.Close    
dbCon.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: In what way does it fail? If it doesn't appear to have any records, please explain how you are observing this. Have you tried in a normal table?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I can't add records using record-set method. Looping from excel column to temporary table in sql. However If I write Insert Into query then it works but not through looping.

Comment: i think you shoud test if r.Value is not Nothing and if Nothing you should be put DBNull.Value

Comment: Doesn't work? Can't? These words are of zero use in solving the problem. How "can't" you? Do you get an error? If you don't get an error, how are you observing that no records are inserted. You have not yet described the symptom.

Comment: What does _Here it fails_ mean in your code? Is there an error?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Here it fails is a comment to show that readers understand where the code starts to fail. Error Descp: "Query cannot be updated because the FROM clause is not a single simple table name."

Comment: I don't understand why you would not state the error in the original question and why it takes _three_ prompts for you to finally state it

Comment: Can you edit the question and add this error message. Can you also _confirm_ that this error is occurring with the code you posted in the original message (not the code posted in the answer below). Can you also try what I suggested - don't use a temporary table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this help (I have not tested:

```
Sub MPNTEST()

Dim dbCon As ADODB.Connection, dbt As ADODB.Recordset
Dim dbtf As ADODB.Field, r As Range, SqlQry1 As String
Dim SQLInsert$

Set dbCon = New ADODB.Connection
'Set dbt = New ADODB.Recordset

dbCon.ConnectionString = SqlConStr

On Error GoTo CloseConnection

''create table db..table
SqlQry1 = "CREATE TABLE tempdb..#TempTbl ( ID INT Primary KEY IDENTITY(1,1),TempData NVARCHAR(255))"

dbCon.Open   
dbCon.Execute (SqlQry1)
dbCon.Execute "use tempdb" ' Move to tempdb

With dbt

    For Each r In ActiveSheet.Range("AE2:AE10")
        SQLInsert = "Insert into #TempTbl(TempData) values('" & Replace(""& r.Value, "'", "''") &"')"
        dbCon.Execute (SQLInsert)
    Next r
End With
'dbt.Close    
dbCon.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Getting error "Query cannot be updated because the FROM clause is not a single simple table name."

Comment: I edit the code again, I don't have a real enviroment as yours, it is just a prototype. Please test. Hope it works fine.

Comment: Hurrah! Its working. What is Dim SQLInsert$ and how does it work so that I understand. However I am very grateful for your help.

Comment: I found the declare here: https://bettersolutions.com/vba/variables/abbreviations.htm